# Printing all the permutations of a string in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, c++11, sorting, combinatorics

It is a code eval challenge question https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/14/.
My answer was accepted, and I modified my code again to improve it. Please let me know is it possible to improve it more.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

void create_permute( std::string &record )
{
    if( !record.empty() ) 
    {
        std::sort( record.begin(), record.end() );
        bool flag=0;
        do{
            if( flag )
            {
                std::cout<<",";
            }
            flag = 1;
            std::cout << record;
        } while( std::next_permutation( record.begin(), record.end() ) );
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
void readInputFile( std::string filename ) 
{

    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open( filename );
    std::string record;
    while( std::getline( infile,record ) )
    {         
       create_permute( record );
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        std::cout << "usage: filesize filename" << "\n";
        exit( 0 );
    }
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );
    readInputFile( argv[ 1 ] );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you have preconditions return early

```
if( !record.empty() ) 
{
    // CODE
}

// If the precondition for doing work is that it is not empty
// Then test and return immediately.

if (record.empty()) {
    return;
}

// CODE
```

Now your code does not suffer lots of indenting and becomes easier to read.

### Use constructors

```
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open( filename );

// Easier to read and write as:
std::ifstream infile( filename );
```

### I think we can simplify that loop:

```
std::sort( record.begin(), record.end() );
std::cout << record;
while( std::next_permutation( record.begin(), record.end() ))
{
    std::cout << ", " << record
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

A boolean tested each time, and firing just once on the first iteration is unaesthetic (and a waste of time). Consider instead

```
    std::cout << record;
    while (std::next_permutation(record.begin(), record.end())) {
        std::cout << ',' << record;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
```

Otherwise looks good. Congratulations for *not* `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good habit to eliminate special cases from your code.  I don't see any particular reason to check for `if ( !record.empty() )`, so don't.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know for a fact that `std::ifstream` automatically at the end of `void readInputFile( std::string )`, there is nothing to add besides what already @vpn and @200_success said.