# Printing all the permutations of a string in alphabetical order-ver1.1

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, combinatorics, c++14

I adapted most of the suggestions from answers for my previous question [Printing all the permutations of a string in alphabetical order](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88285/printing-all-the-permutations-of-a-string-in-alphabetical-order) to rewrote my solution again. Please let me know any more changes required or any more suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

void create_permute(  std::string& record )
{
    std::sort( record.begin(), record.end() );
    std::cout<<record;

    while( std::next_permutation( record.begin(), record.end() ) )
    {           
        std::cout<<","<<record;     
    } 
    std::cout << "\n";    
}
void readInputFile( std::string filename ) 
{    
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    std::string record;
    while( std::getline( infile,record ) )
    {        
       create_permute( record );
    }
    infile.close();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        std::cout << "usage: filesize filename" << "\n";
        exit( 0 );
    }
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );
    readInputFile( argv[ 1 ] );   

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing I would bother about complaing about in real code review.

But for argument's sake:

### Pass by const ref

Rather than passing by value. It usually means that an extra copy will be removed. In this case that's not true but I think its a good habit.

```
void readInputFile( std::string const& filename )
```

### No need to return 0 from main

If `main()` can not return anything else. Then I don't bother with a `return` statement in `main` (it's special). The compiler adds a `return 0` if no `return` is provided for `main`.

Personally I use this (that face that I have not added a return) to indicate that the application has no real failure state.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said by @Loki Astari, you could add some  input parameter check, for example: *stream tests/ error handling*,
 after `std::ifstream infile(filename);` in `void readInputFile( std::string filename )` to check `stream states` and, eventually, recover from: `bad()`, `fail()`, `stream.open()`(not open).

An example would be:

```
int i=0;
cin>>i; 
if(!cin){ // true only if input operation failed
    if(cin.bad())error("cin is bad") // stream corrupted (serious problem)
    if(cin.eof()){ // no more input 

    }
    if(cin.fail()){ // unexpected input (wrong type/format)
        cin.clean() // reset state flags
        // use char, error("invalid symbol: ", char) and unget() 
        // to make clear what is wrong 
    }
}
```